# Angular Datatables with Json Datasource from Ajax

Tags: angularjs, json, ajax, angular-datatables

Hi i am Trying to bind datatables with ajax Datasource from server, i am able to get data from server but unable to bind to Table

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('ajax', {
        url: fundingPartnerService.getState(),
        type: 'GET'
    })
    .withDataProp('item3')
    .withOption('order', [])
    .withBootstrap()
    .withDOM('<"row" <"col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-6" l ><"col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-6" f >> <"row" <"col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12" rt>> <"row" <"col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-6" i ><"col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-6" p >>')
    .withBootstrapOptions({
        pagination: {
            classes: {
                ul: 'pagination pagination-datatables'
            }
        }
    })
    .withOption('fnRowCallback',
    function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        $compile(nRow)($scope);
    });
$scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('stateCode').withTitle('State'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Select State')
        .notSortable()
        .withOption('searchable', false)
        .withClass('select-checkbox')
        .renderWith(function () { return '<input type="checkbox"/>'; }),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Select County')
        .notSortable()
        .withOption('searchable', false)
        .withClass('select-checkbox')
        .renderWith(function (data, type, row) {
            return '<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="selectCountyState(\'' + row.stateCode + '\')" value="select County"/>';
        })

];
$scope.dtColumnDefs = [DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(0).notSortable()]
```

Below is response i am getting from server:

```
{"item1":true,"item2":"","item3":[{"stateCode":"0 ","stateName":"UNKNOWN"},{"stateCode":"AK","stateName":"Alaska"},{"stateCode":"AL","stateName":"Alabama"},{"stateCode":"AR","stateName":"Arkansas"},{"stateCode":"AZ","stateName":"Arizona"},{"stateCode":"CA","stateName":"California"},{"stateCode":"CO","stateName":"Colorado"},{"stateCode":"CT","stateName":"Connecticut"},{"stateCode":"DC","stateName":"D.C."},{"stateCode":"DE","stateName":"Delaware"},{"stateCode":"FL","stateName":"Florida"},{"stateCode":"GA","stateName":"Georgia"},{"stateCode":"HI","stateName":"Hawaii"},{"stateCode":"IA","stateName":"Iowa"},{"stateCode":"ID","stateName":"Idaho"},{"stateCode":"IL","stateName":"Illinois"},{"stateCode":"IN","stateName":"Indiana"},{"stateCode":"KS","stateName":"Kansas"},{"stateCode":"KY","stateName":"Kentucky"},{"stateCode":"LA","stateName":"Louisiana"},{"stateCode":"MA","stateName":"Massachusetts"},{"stateCode":"MD","stateName":"Maryland"},{"stateCode":"ME","stateName":"Maine"},{"stateCode":"MI","stateName":"Michigan"},{"stateCode":"MN","stateName":"Minnesota"},{"stateCode":"MO","stateName":"Missouri"},{"stateCode":"MS","stateName":"Mississippi"},{"stateCode":"MT","stateName":"Montana"},{"stateCode":"NC","stateName":"North Carolina"},{"stateCode":"ND","stateName":"North Dakota"},{"stateCode":"NE","stateName":"Nebraska"},{"stateCode":"NH","stateName":"New Hampshire"},{"stateCode":"NJ","stateName":"New Jersey"},{"stateCode":"NM","stateName":"New Mexico"},{"stateCode":"NV","stateName":"Nevada"},{"stateCode":"NY","stateName":"New York"},{"stateCode":"OH","stateName":"Ohio"},{"stateCode":"OK","stateName":"Oklahoma"},{"stateCode":"OR","stateName":"Oregon"},{"stateCode":"PA","stateName":"Pennsylvania"},{"stateCode":"RI","stateName":"Rhode Island"},{"stateCode":"SC","stateName":"South Carolina"},{"stateCode":"SD","stateName":"South Dakota"},{"stateCode":"TN","stateName":"Tennessee"},{"stateCode":"TX","stateName":"Texas"},{"stateCode":"UN","stateName":"Unknown"},{"stateCode":"UT","stateName":"Utah"},{"stateCode":"VA","stateName":"Virginia"},{"stateCode":"VT","stateName":"Vermont"},{"stateCode":"WA","stateName":"Washington"},{"stateCode":"WI","stateName":"Wisconsin"},{"stateCode":"WV","stateName":"West Virginia"},{"stateCode":"WY","stateName":"Wyoming"}]}
```

Below is error Messsage i am getting from datatables
[image]

Comment: It works fine here -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/6Vcf51iqsP45Xlz4grDc?p=preview**

Comment: with the api Provided in the Plunker it is Working fine. I need to Add promise to laod the data using my server API
 `.fromFnPromise(function() {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        fundingPartnerService.getState().then(function(result) {
            defer.resolve(result.item3);
        });
        return defer.promise;
    })`  
 Thanks@davidkonrad